# Enable touchpad powershell

Tags: powershell, touchpad

I'm trying to write a Windows Powershell program that executes once every minute and enables the hardware installed touchpad. I have never touched Powershell before, so I have 0 experience regarding what is required to do this.

The program only needs to work on my machine, which is a Toshiba S55T-B.

To enable the touchpad manually, one goes to the icons on the task bar selects -> Toshiba Pointing Device -> Property of Touch-Pad -> ELAN -> (select Elan Smart-Pad) -> Enable Device -> Apply.

How can I accomplish this? Thanks,

Comment: Unless you know that this device comes with PowerShell cmdlets, the answer to your question will not be PowerShell-specific (except for putting the programmatic ways you do find into PowerShell terms). I suggest you look at [devcon.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff544707%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396), which, obviously, you'd be able to invoke from PowerShell.

Comment: Thanks mklement0, It's Enable. I'll change it.  I'll look in to DevCon and update accordingly.